# Convert variant type to BSON

Tags: opa

I have the following variant:

`type variant = {one} / {two:int} / {three:string}`

Using the opa2doc() method, I want to be able to ask my MongoDB database for all rows that contains a specific variant value (one, two or three) without taking into account the values for each variant. I'm using the low-level mongodb API.

I tried something like:

`opa2doc({ kind={two=_} })`

but it doesn't works.

It works for `opa2doc({ kind={one} })` because this variant doesn't have any attached datas.

Any idea how to make this work ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to use binding to native MongoDB [query API](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/method/db.collection.find/) you probably need to build a proper MongoDB query document. Queries finding a pattern (instead of comparing with equality) use special [query operators](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/query/) which are JSON values. Opa's high-level DB API do this for you using its own, ML-like, operators. Native MongoDB query document for your case would need [`$exists` operator](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/query/exists/#op._S_exists):

```
{ "kind.two": { $exists: true } }
```

In old syntax it should be:

```
Bson.opa2doc({ `kind.two`= { `$exists`= true } })
```

Comment: Yeah I tried this and it compiles ! But MongoDB systematically returns 0 !

Comment: Did you check the query in `mongo` interactive console? Try the "dot notation": `{ "kind.two": { $exists: true } }`.

Comment: And it works ! I already tried it but had a syntax error ! I forgot the use of the ` operator with the old (and awesome) ocaml syntax : ```{`kind.two`={`$exists`=true}}```

Comment: Answer updated, so others can also benefit from your efforts :)